# Split two programs to half screen when launch using batch file

Tags: windows, batch

I want to launch two excel files but split them to occupy half of the screen vertically. Any one can help, please !

```
start excel "C:\Users\vb88\OneDrive\SPORT\Double.xls"
ping /n 10 localhost>nul 2>&1
start excel "C:\Users\vb88|OneDrive\SPORT\Overview.xls"
```

Comment: Possible cross site duplicate [cmd - How can a batch file run a program and set the position and size of the window? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10392620/how-can-a-batch-file-run-a-program-and-set-the-position-and-size-of-the-window)

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/command-line-switches-for-microsoft-office-products-079164cd-4ef5-4178-b235-441737deb3a6#Category=Excel `c:\> excel /a progID` - obscure mention / description of a feature that might be useful. NOTE: INCOMPLETE DOCUMENTATION ERROR.

Comment: @Hannu, I don't understand what you meant ?

Comment: Well,  the text behind the link tells there is a `c:\> excel /a progID` way of launching either a macro or some kind of plugin, but it tells nothing more...